# In Http.get, what's the difference between response.on('data') and using the bl library in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');
var url = process.argv[2];

http.get(url, function(res) {
  res.pipe(bl(function(err, data) {
    var dataString = data.toString();
    var dataCount = dataString.length
    console.log(dataCount);
    console.log(dataString);
  }));
})

   // 
// http.get(url, function(res) {
//   res.on('data', function(data) {
//     var dataString = data.toString();
//     var dataCount = dataString.length
//     console.log(dataCount);
//     console.log(dataString);
//   });
// })
```

This is from the node school challenges (learnyounode). It's exercise 8.

The commented out code outputs each individual word and seems to break the data up and not aggregate that data. I am trying to find docs explaining this behavior but I cannot. Can someone shed a light on what's going on?

Comment: Why do you think that? What is the output of the second snippet compared to the first snippet? (Please add that output to the question itself rather than in a comment).

Comment: I am getting the code challenge from node school so I can't actually output this since I don't have a valid path that the tutorial uses.

Answer (score 1):

`res` is a [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), which means that it will emit `data` events when it has read *some* data. This doesn't necessarily have to be *all* the data, and it may get called multiple times (until either an `end` event is called, or an `error` event signals something went wrong).

That's basically what `bl` does (in your example): it collects all the data, and when it has all been read, it calls the callback function you pass it.

Without `bl` the code would look something like this:

```
http.get(url, function(res) {
  var buffers = [];
  res.on('data', function(data) {
    buffers.push(data);
  }).on('end', function() {
    var dataString = Buffer.concat(buffers).toString();
    var dataCount  = dataString.length
    console.log(dataCount);
    console.log(dataString);
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    ...handle the error...
  });
});
```

In other words: the incoming data is collected in the `buffers` array, and when the `end` event is triggered (meaning all the data has been read), the data buffers are concatenated together to form the final data buffer.

Comment: "...will emit data events when it has read some data.". When does it emit? On blank spaces?What constitutes some data? My console.log seem to be logging every individual word and not the aggregated data. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Jwan622 let's just say that you cannot assume anything about when it gets triggered (unless the stream you're reading from is in object mode). It may be 1 byte, 100 bytes, 1000 bytes (but not 0 bytes, though). It depends on a lot of variables (like rate of incoming data, if there are other streams in use, etc).